Disable Spell check on VS 2022 for a specific file location?
I'm getting thousands of spelling errors for a decompiled bit of code in AppData... not even code in my actual source code... Does anyone know how to exclude the spell checker spamming me like crazy?

I want to keep spell checking on, but just not for decompiled files!

If you want to turn off the spell checker, select Edit > Advanced > Toggle Spell Checker to turn off the spell checker. For more information, please refer to the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/text-spell-checker?view=vs-2022
